# Adicionar Objetos dentro de uma Array em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

preciso chegar nesse resultado aqui:

```
[ 
   { 
      alu_id: 10,
      alu_nome: 'Edson Santana dos Santos',
      notas: { 
                dis_id: 1, dis_nome: 'Português', nota: 25 
             } 
   },
   { 
      alu_id: 11,
      alu_nome: 'Larissa Manoela da Silva',
      notas: { dis_id: 3, dis_nome: 'História', nota: 28 },
             { dis_id: 1, dis_nome: 'Português', nota: 29 },
             { dis_id: 2, dis_nome: 'Matemática', nota: 25 }
]
```

Porém está saindo esse resultado:

```
[ 
   { 
      alu_id: 10,
      alu_nome: 'Edson Santana dos Santos',
      notas: { dis_id: 1, dis_nome: 'Português', nota: 25 } 
   },
   { 
      alu_id: 11,
      alu_nome: 'Larissa Manoela da Silva',
      notas: { dis_id: 2, dis_nome: 'Matemática', nota: 25 } 
   },
   { 
      alu_id: 11,
      alu_nome: 'Larissa Manoela da Silva',
      notas: { dis_id: 3, dis_nome: 'História', nota: 28 } 
   },
   { 
      alu_id: 11,
      alu_nome: 'Larissa Manoela da Silva',
      notas: { dis_id: 1, dis_nome: 'Português', nota: 29 } 
   } 
]
```

CÓDIGO FONTE:

```
const data = {                        
                disciplinas: [],
                alunos: []                        
             }                   

for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
   data.disciplinas.push({
      dis_id: results[i].dis_id,
      dis_nome: results[i].dis_nome
   })                        
   data.alunos.push({
      alu_id: results[i].alu_id,
      alu_nome: results[i].alu_nome,
      notas: {
                dis_id: results[i].dis_id,
                dis_nome: results[i].dis_nome,
                nota: results[i].notas_valor
             }                            
   })                                               
}
```

DADOS DO BANCO:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenha uma variável para controlar se você está fazendo outro `data.alunos.push()` para o mesmo aluno. Declare essa variável **antes** do `for`. Exemplo:

```
var alu_id_anterior = null
```

Assim que for tratar os dados dos alunos, faça antes o teste:

```
if (results[i].alu_id === alu_id_anterior) {
    // outra nota para o mesmo aluno
} else {
    // primeira vez que trata o aluno
}
```

Quando cair no bloco do `if` faça o *push* apenas da nota:

```
data.alunos[data.alunos.length - 1].notas.push({
    dis_id: results[i].dis_id,
    dis_nome: results[i].dis_nome,
    nota: results[i].notas_valor
})
```

Quando cair no bloco do `else`, faça o *push* do aluno juntamente com a nota, conforme você já estava fazendo.

Como última instrução do `for`, guarde o id do aluno que você acabou de processar.

```
alu_id_anterior = results[i].alu_id
```

Para que tudo isso funcione, é **fundamental** que o resultado da sua consulta à tabela esteja ordenado por `alu_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Estás a usar `data.alunos.push` para inserir novos dados na array, quando devias usar `.push` no aluno específico. Para isso `notas` tem de ser uma array e tens de encontrar o aluno no qual queres inserir as notas.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
const results = [{
    alu_id: 10,
    alu_nome: 'Edson Santana dos Santos',
    notas: {
      dis_id: 1,
      dis_nome: 'Português',
      nota: 25
    }
  },
  {
    alu_id: 11,
    alu_nome: 'Larissa Manoela da Silva',
    notas: {
      dis_id: 2,
      dis_nome: 'Matemática',
      nota: 25
    }
  },
  {
    alu_id: 11,
    alu_nome: 'Larissa Manoela da Silva',
    notas: {
      dis_id: 3,
      dis_nome: 'História',
      nota: 28
    }
  },
  {
    alu_id: 11,
    alu_nome: 'Larissa Manoela da Silva',
    notas: {
      dis_id: 1,
      dis_nome: 'Português',
      nota: 29
    }
  }
];

function organizarNotas() {
  const data = results.reduce((alunos, entrada) => {
  const id = entrada.alu_id;
    const aluno = alunos[id];
    if (!alunos[id]) {
      alunos[id] = {
        ...entrada,
        notas: []
      }
    }
    
    alunos[id].notas.push(entrada.notas);
    return alunos;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(data);
}

console.log('Notas:', organizarNotas(results));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Sergio, deu muito certo sua função, está me retornando o que eu preciso!